# how to retrieve select value from html drop down list with php?

Tags: php, html

Enter your information in the form below:

**Userid:**

**Password:**

**Name:**

**Gender:**
     Male
     Female

**Date Of Birth:**
    
     - Day - 
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19
    20
    21
    22
    23
    24
    25
    26
    27
    28
    29
    30
    31
    

    
     - Month - 
    January
    Feburary
    March
    April
    May
    June
    July
    August
    September
    October
    November
    December

Copyright 2013 by Online Catwalk.   All rights reserved.

Comment: there is textbox for date of birth year

Comment: Is this even a question? What about code?

Comment: <form action="registerProfile.php" method="post">

<fieldset>
 <legend>Enter your information in the form below:</legend>
 
 
 <p>
 <b>Date Of Birth:</b>
 <select name = "DateOfBirth_Day">
 <option> - Day - </option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>

Comment: <select name = "DateOfBirth_Month">
 <option> - Month - </option>
 <option value="January">January</option>
 <option value="February">Feburary</option>
 <option value="March">March</option>
 <option value="April">April</option>
 <option value="May">May</option>

Comment: <input type = "text" name = "DateOfBirth_Year" size"10" maxlength="8" value=""/>

Comment: if(is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] = '1970')){
 $DateOfBirth_Year = $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'];
} 
else if (is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] < '1970')){
 echo '<p><font color = "red">Please enter the year above 1970!</font></p>';
}

else {
 echo '<p><font color="red">Enter NUMBER for the year of date of birth!</font></p>';
}

Comment: how to make that the year for textbox above 1970

Comment: must be number ........must not be null

Answer (score 1):

Posted form values are in the array:

```
$_POST[]
```

indexed by the name of the form element.  So, if your `select` looks like this:

```
<select name="gender">
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

Then when the form is posted to the server, the server-side code can access the value here:

```
$_POST['gender']
```

For example:

```
if ($_POST['gender'] == '1') {
    // male
} else if ($_POST['gender'] == '2') {
    // female
} else {
    // unexpected value
}
```

Comment: may i know how to put validation for textbox for year

Comment: <input type = "text" name = "DateOfBirth_Year" size"10" maxlength="8" value=""/>

Comment: @user3151494: "Validation" is a pretty broad concept.  If you want to check values in server-side code, then you'd do that with something like an `if` statement.  `if ($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] < 1970) { // year is too low }` for example.  At this point, I recommend walking through some introductory PHP tutorials to learn about expressing logic like this in your code.

Comment: how to set certain month have certain day like february for 28 days

Comment: if(is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year']< 1970 || $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year']<= 2014)){//$DateOfBirth_Year is A NUMBER
 $DateOfBirth_Year = $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'];
}
else{
 
 echo '<p><font color="red">Enter NUMBER for the year of date of birth!</font></p>';
}

Comment: @user3151494: Date validation can get complex very quickly.  I recommend looking for a date/time library to help with this.  (Though I don't know of any for PHP.)